# ListPlot3D doesn't work

Tags: plotting, listplot3d

I want to display my data as a table {{x1,y1,z1},...,{xn,yn,zn}} using ListPlot3D, but it doesn't work correctly[image].
On version 11.2, the exact same code worked fine, but for some reason not on 13.0. The plot should look like a triangle at z=1, the vertices of which are located in (0,0), (-1,-1), (1,-1).
Data looks like this (not full data)
[image]
Code
[image]

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please load a minimal example with Mathematica code that can be copied, pasted and executed locally in our own notebook sessions. It is difficult to offer concrete advice in the absence of usable code. Thanks.